# Run Test button/link gives error: command 'sfdx.force.apex.test.class.run.delegate' not found

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

In Visual Studio Code setup with SFDX links appear above each test method/class that are clickable and presumably would run the appropriate test.

However these have never worked for me, I just get the error:

> command 'sfdx.force.apex.test.class.run.delegate' not found

or

> command 'sfdx.force.apex.test.method.run.delegate' not found

Depending on if I click on *Run Test* or *Run All Tests*.

How do I fix this error and get these buttons to work?